# Anyone suggest a good ssh terminal emulator for windows (connecting to RHEL box) and proper terminal type?

Tags: terminal, emulation, xterm

We have an old C program which has traditionally been run from SCO boxes.  We have a customer that went with RackSpace running RHEL and we got the app recompiled.  We have a problem with terminal emulation though.  We've been trying PuTTY over SSH, but we can't seem to get the emulation settings right so that we can use the keyboard, arrow keys, and numeric keypad. We've tried SCO, linux, Xterm, VT100+.  If we use ansi_sysk, the number pad works, but arrow keys don't.  If we use xterm, the arrow keys work, but number pad doesn't.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would try [Ericom Powerterm](http://www.ericom.com/terminal_emulator.asp), specifically with the SCO-ANSI emulation mode. I've worked with a legacy application for years where PuTTY required heavy modification to get the font, display and keybindings to work properly. Powerterm always worked out of the box, but is a commercial application, so cost became an issue.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the client has telnet closed, so I'm working to get them to open it up.  We are going to give this a shot.

Comment: Telnet is probably a bad idea, as it sends authentication data in the clear

Comment: It's a legacy app. Sometimes SSH is not available.

Answer (score 0):

[SecureCRT](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/) has to be the benchmark for native Windows ssh clients. Highly configurable with a design that fits well in to a Windows workflow. It's a paid application so, as with most paid apps, means you can email their support for issues.