# Function keys over SSH/PuTTY to SCO unix

Tags: ssh, putty, unix

I am trying to set up SSH to a SCO Unix server that runs custom software that uses the function keys on the keyboard, however the keys do not appear to be in the correct format for SCO to recognise. None of the keyboard options on PuTTY work, including the SCO option.

How do I change the keycodes that SCO/bash is looking for when it wants a function key? If it helps, the system is upgrading from Wyse50 terminals.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an ANSI or SCO ANSI emulation type.

The keybindings will be the biggest trick, but in my experience, `ansi`, `ansi25` and `scoansi` have been winners for me.

For the keybindings, go to:

Session > Terminal > Keyboard

[image]

Also see the following for terminal type/string suggestions:

[How to change the terminal to SCO compliant in Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/429901/how-to-change-the-terminal-to-sco-compliant-in-ubuntu/429918#429918)

[Anyone suggest a good ssh terminal emulator for windows (connecting to RHEL box) and proper terminal type?](https://serverfault.com/questions/279291/anyone-suggest-a-good-ssh-terminal-emulator-for-windows-connecting-to-rhel-box/279295#279295)

Comment: I have tried all of the "Function keys and keypad" settings, but none of them work. I was looking to change what the SCO server expects to see for them.

Comment: You're going to have less luck modifying your SCO-side termdef and more luck fixing the client side. Did you also change the terminal-type string in `Session > Data`? So you're going from terminals to PuTTY on PC's? Just to check, I would download an evaluation of [Ericom Powerterm](http://www.ericom.com/terminal_emulator.asp) to make sure that this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

As a long time SCO consultant, I concur, download the Ericom PowerTerm Lite and use it. It is around $79 per license.  It is all we recommend and we have it running on Win 8 with pass through printing.  Key mapping works great.